# Cooking issue with cheap plastic forks

Tags: utensils

I was cooking rice, beans and sausage for my friend and I but since we are living very low budget my only utensils were plastic forks, knives, and spoons (really cheap ones that come in packs of like 48).  I was picking up the sausage in pieces and putting them in a bowl when I noticed the fork had begun to melt.  Luckily these are not for until tomorrow but I was wondering if it is safe to eat them since the fork did not seem to leave any plastic behind and was only in the sausage for about 30 seconds.  I just don't want to feed my friend contaminated sausage. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you make a habit of it, you should be fine. But if I were you, I'd check how much a set of used silverware is (at a garage sale or thriftstore). I have a hunch that buying two packs of plastic ones costs more...

Comment: It's none of my business, not knowing your situation, nor do I know where you're located, but IKEA sells 24 piece stainless steel cutlery sets starting from €10 / £7.75 / $8. Is plastic cutlery really much more cost effective?

Comment: And I forgot: Your metal forks and spoons can do double duty as cooking utensils in pots and (non-nonstick) pans, your plastic ones obviously can't.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Right! And there's craigslist, freecycle etc. Sometimes people are simply happy that Granny's old stuff will be used again instead of going to the dumpster.

Comment: Well its actually that my friend and I are in an exchange program to America and won't be able to do anything with silverware once we have to leave so we thought it better to just get plastic.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Dev : Thrift stores and/or yard sales are your friend -- you can often get a few utensils for couple of dollars.  Even if you can't bring them home with you, you can either sell them off to someone else or donate them back to the thrift store.  Your next best options are dollar stores -- still inexpensive, but they're likely of lower quality (although new, not used)

Comment: Think about it this way. There are bound to be laws that govern the materials that eating utensils are made from, and it would be very strange if those laws didn't cover the possibility that the utensils may get hot! You and your friend are quite safe

Comment: Are you located in the US? If so, I have so much stuff I would be happy to send you a set of 8 piece cutlery, since my parents passed away very recently and my kids are just giving things away for the last 4 months to friends and people they know who can use things.  I'm sure I can find it.  Plastic and paper is when you get older and for desert and are too lazy to do dishes.  My friends and I are great examples of that.  Don't use plastic to cook, it's not good and it could break while you are using it and you could burn your hand, bad idea.  Also, someone said, it is an expensive proposition

Answer (score 1):

1. The plastic fork just melt (soften) a little bit, no biggie, you should be able to eat that.
2. You should buy cheap cutlery at the dollar store, you do not need many, maybe 4 sets (fork, spoon knife); when your exchange session is over, just leave them in your apartment; no need to bring them back with you.
3. Using real cutlery and washing them is better for the environment than using cheap plastic cutlery and throwing them in the trash (*)

(*) Unless you buy expensive biodegradable or compostable cutlery.

Comment: Various studies have shown that the energy used to make and wash cups is more than their lifetimes worth energy to make polystyrene cups. May apply to plastic forks too?

Answer (score 1):

No it won't hurt you but for the money you spend on plastic you can find stainless at a thrift store or garage sale.